# Linking a SKScene with an UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I am trying to link up a SKScene with an UIViewController. Now I know this question has been posted before, but none of them are in Swift and my whole game is programmed in Swift. Anyways when you first create a SpriteKit game two default files are generated a GameScene.swift and a GameViewController.swift. These two seemed to be "linked up" by using:

```
    extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as MainMenuScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I tried doing this myself by making a MainMenuViewController.swift. I then pasted the same code from above in the file. I then connected in via Interface Builder, meaning I set the class of a ViewController to be MainMenuViewController.swift. This all seemed to work fine but when I compiled everything I got an error that said: Invalid redeclaration of 'unarchiveFromFile'. How can I have the same effect of the default generated files being "linked up" with my main menu scene?

Comment: none of them are in swift? I beg to differ: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=skscene+uiviewcontroller+swift